# Windows 10 with BitLocker: AutoUnlock second drive for data recovery

Tags: windows-10, encryption, bitlocker

I have a BitLocker setup where C: is encrypted and D: as well using the same encryption setup. D: is set to auto unlock upon startup and that works well under normal circumstances.

I am facing now a data recovery task. Booting Windows 10 into a recovery console allows me to unlock the C: drive using the BitLocker recovery key and then enter the users password. I do fail to access the D: drive though - how is that possible from the recovery console?

Comment: "How is that possible from the recovery console?" - You must use the passphrase to unlock it.  The simplest solution is to use another instance of Windows.

Comment: Hi again :) I can't use another instance of Windows as this is a laptop which I currently am not able to open and remove the SSD. The D: drive is also BitLocker encrypted but shares the key with the C: drive (hence the auto unlock). Funny thing is, I found all the data from the D: drive in a found.000 folder now...

Comment: If you are finding data in a folder called found.000 you have discovered the reason Windows does not boot.  You have suffered a hardware failure.  This would also explain your permissions problems on the system partition.